# Is there an alternate term to "fired" for the Reaction Control System?

Tags: astronauts, terminology, rcs

Do the astronauts use any word, other than "fired" when referring to the use of the Reaction Control System for attitude control or translation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One can "start" or "execute" the "burn" or the "maneuver".

Examples are found in the [Shuttle Crew Operations Manual](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/johnson/pdf/390651main_shuttle_crew_operations_manual.pdf)

- on page 7.2-3

> To perform an automatic maneuver, the crew first enters the required
>   data on the UNIV PTG display for the desired maneuver. To start the
>   maneuver at a set time, that time is also entered on the UNIV PTG
>   display. After checking the data, the crew enters an Item 18, 19, or
>   20, as appropriate, to **start the maneuver**. With AUTO DAP selected, an
>   auto maneuver will begin at the set time or as soon as Item 18, 19, or
>   20 is entered if the maneuver start time is in the past. Item 21 is
>   used to cancel a maneuver.

- on page 7.2-5

> Orbit translation maneuvers can be conducted using the OMS engines or
>   RCS jets. The OMS engines are usually used for larger maneuvers. Burn
>   targets for preplanned orbit OMS or RCS burns are normally transmitted
>   to the crew from Mission Control. The crew will then load those (or
>   verify auto-loaded) targets and **execute the burn** at the appropriate
>   time. OMS/RCS burn monitoring and control for orbit burns is similar
>   to that discussed in Section 7.3.

- on page 7.3-3

> One technique for +X RCS burns is called the Patterson Maneuver. Here,
>   the crew first maneuvers the vehicle to the proper burn attitude, as
>   displayed on the MNVR EXEC display. Then they pitch the nose up 3°
>   high. So, when they **start the burn** with the THC, the vehicle will
>   pitch down to the correct attitude, since aft RCS jets are above the
>   c.g., and the 3° deadband will hold it there. A variation on the
>   technique is to **start the burn** in attitude, allow the vehicle to pitch
>   down toward the 3° deadband limit, then pitch up 6° to the other side
>   of the deadband. The vehicle will slowly pitch back down and hold the
>   desired attitude.

(emphasis mine)